# Python Pyplot won't plot surface fully

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the attached picture you can see two plots of the same data. The left one is plotted with `plot_wireframe()` the right one with `plot_surface()`

Like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xm, ym, Values)

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax2.plot_wireframe(xm, ym, Values)

plt.show()
```

Why is this? The `plot_wireframe` is correct. Why is for example the peak in the left upper corner not shown on the surface plot? Thanks

[image: the two plots of the same data]

Here, another example with the data matrix:

[image]

Comment: Did you try rotating the plot on the right? The peak in the wire frame does not poke out when viewed in 3D.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, when I rotate the graph its still not correct, but wait a sec, I upload a second example with the data matrix too. Thx for the help!

Comment: I think what @MadPhysicist is saying, is that your plots are at different angles, enough that you might just not see the peaks you are looking for.

Comment: Ah, ok, but then nope, it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

Given what the discussion in the comments, I *think* what's going on is you have a normal wireframe that looks as it should, but the surface plot is a 2D projection in that 3D axes object. I noticed that you are missing a line that shows up in [the matplotlib surface example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html): `X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)`. Assuming I'm on the right track, you need to insert an analogous statement prior to the `axes.plot_surface()` call.

Comment: Nope, I use the meshgrid function, but thanks for the idea!